# How to make a rip effect when touching on a folder like that in iOS' springboard?

Tags: android, animation, layout

[Espier Launcher](http://www.addictivetips.com/mobile/get-the-ios-springboard-on-your-android-homescreen-with-espier-launcher/) is a launcher app for Android that has nearly 100% copied the design of the springboard app in iOS, now I am curious about the rip effect that when a folder is touched, the home screen is ripped and the folder is expanded, like the screenshot in the following:

[image]

Now I am scratching my head and got a clue coming out, but it is not easy to implement and I doubt it is the solution.

This is my thought: take a screenshot of the entire screen before a folder is touched, use this screenshot to create a rip effect which will be used as a background image for the final effect, so the expanded folder will be something like an overlay. This is the method I can think of that makes a little sense to me, but it does not feel elegant to me.

Maybe I need to override GridView and extend it to support what I want, then where to start?

Comment: Did you find any solution? i am also working on same.

Comment: I have Got the solution Yipeeeeeee!

Comment: @DeepikaLalra, could you post your solution as the answer?

Comment: give me your email id i will mail you. if you like that solution then use it.

Comment: Hi, @DeepikaLalra, thank you, but if only you email your solution to me, I may be the only one that you help, but if you post your solution as the answer, it may help someone else in the future. and it is most likely that people will improve your solution. SO is a place where we share knowledge together.

Comment: After many years, I come across this old question, and I think I need to add a comment to describe how I solved the problem. Yes, I did it as my original thought, it worked pretty well then.